# what is a KeyError in Python 3.5/Pandas?

Tags: python, twitter

I work with files were exported from stream twitter . but when run code 
then error : KeyError: 'text' on 
tweets['python'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('python', tweet)).
how to fix it ? thank everyone..!.

```html
import re
import json
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
tweets_data_path = '...\\..\\log1000.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue 
def word_in_text(word, text):
    word = word.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.search(word, text)
    if match:
        return True
    return False
#------------------------DataFrame--------------------------
tweets = pd.DataFrame() 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
tweets['python'] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text('python', tweet))
#----------------------------------------------------------------
print (tweets['python'].value_counts()[True])
```

Answer (score 0):

Key Error means data with such key was not found in dictionary/data frame.

Comment: you can help me . how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you show columns in twets? For example `list(tweets.columns)`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any data in you DataFrame. Try:

`tweets = pd.DataFrame(data=tweets_data, columns=['tweets'])`

Comment: replace 'text' with 'tweets'

Comment: i'm try but error message . AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: That is an issue with your ```word_in_text function```. One of more of your tweets is stored as a float. Not text.